# Change outlook default search behavior

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, search

I'm using v 15.13.1 of Outlook for Mac. I'm trying to figure out how to change the default search behavior from "search this folder" to "search all folders", as I rarely change to the correct folder first.

I know this was possible on old versions of Outlook on Windows so I am hoping it's possible here as well.

Thanks!