# Is it possible to change Outlook 2016 default search

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is it possible to change the default search behaviour in Outlook

[Change outlook default search behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/1028038/change-outlook-default-search-behavior) is for Mac, this question is about Windows

For example, the default search appears to be a contains search. For example, if I searched for `sand`, then `sandwhiches` would also be a match.

I am aware I can use quote marks and search for "sand" but my question is can I change the default search behaviour?

Comment: So you’re asking if there’s a way to change it per the example you provided where if you type in a `string` and it is not double quoted for that to be treated as if it were double quoted and `"literal"` just like that, correct. I looked over the standard *Search* options and saw nothing that appears relevant. Since Outlook 2016 is not open-source, I'd be surprised if changing that functionality with that specific feature were possible in an easy fashion or where legality may not be questionable or concerning to those technically able to complete the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the default search behavior, which is why you have multiple ways of [narrowing your search down](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da).

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in option in Outlook to switch between "contains search" or "exact match". You have you use the quote marks or the phrase match option in Advanced search:
[image]